# How can I access AWS Secrets Manager from my Lambda within a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-secrets-manager

I am working on a native AWS .NET 6 application with many AWS services being used, such as **AWS Lambda, AWS SQS/SNS, AWS EventBridge, DynamoDB, S3,** and so on.

I am migrating many of my controllers in my Web API project which is running on an **EC2** instance to **AWS Lambda Serverless** API. This means that my Lambda needs access to my **RDS Postgresql** instance which is only accessible through **VPC**. My Lambda needs to be in a VPC in order to make a connection to the RDS.

However, I have stored all my keys and configurations in **AWS Secrets Manager**. And as you may now, my Lambda cannot access secrets manager because it's in a VPC. I have read many answers and other articles about solutions for that, but I still don't fully understand it. What is the best and a free way to allow my Lambda to access Secrets Manager and also being in a VPC at the same time?

Comment: VPC endpoint for secrets manager

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-to-aws-secrets-manager-service-within-a-virtual-private-cloud/

Comment: Your Lambda function is not failing to access AWS Secrets Manager "because it's in a VPC". It's failing because it has no network route to the AWS Secrets Manager API endpoint. You're going to have the same issue with SQS, SNS, DynamoDB etc. You need to decide if [PrivateLink](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/) is your preferred solution or if NAT and IGW is your preferred solution - probably PrivateLink, I would guess, because of the cost of NAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments on my answer. I managed to make it work. I did the following steps to make it work:

- I created a **VPC Endpoint**
- I selected the secretsmanager service, which in my region is '`com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.secretsmanager`'
- Created a separate **Security Group** for the Endpoint.
- Created a separate **Security Group** for my AWS Lambda.
- For the Endpoint's Security Group, I added a rule for both `Inboud` and `Outbound` selecting HTTPS, port 443, and the Lambda's SG.
- For the AWS Lambda's Security group, I did the same as the previous step but selected the VPC Endpoint's SG.

And voila, my lambda worked

Of course, not to forget to mention this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-connect-to-aws-secrets-manager-service-within-a-virtual-private-cloud/